# Calculating test characteristics

Tags: r

I have a 2x2 contingency table from a larger dataset:

```
> ct
        disease
    test   0   1
     no  118  12
     yes  24  46
```

and I would like to quickly retrieve the different (medical) diagnostic test characteristics such as

- Sensitivity
- Specificity
- Likelihood Ratio +
- Likelihood Ratio -
- False positive rate
- False negative rate
- Prob of disease
- Pred value positive
- Pred value negative
- p(neg test wrong)
- p(test positive)
- p(test negative)
- Overall accuracy

with their respective 95% CIs. Is there a package/function that does that? Many thanks.

Comment: Maybe [this](http://finzi.psych.upenn.edu/R/library/epiR/html/epi.tests.html) can help you...

Comment: This stuff is easily looked up.

Comment: @DWin -- will you please actually help answer the question? Many thanks.

Comment: Try setting `verbose = TRUE`, It does give `LRN` and `LRP` as `plr` and `nlr`. Have a look at the help file `?epi.test`, or the link previously mentioned, and you will see it does calculate most of the things you want/

Comment: I was just explaining my downvote. I think downvotes without a corresponding comment are gratuitous and unhelpful. I think commented downvotes are informative.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, `epi.tests(t, verbose=T)` it is.

Answer (score 1):

Possibly you could write a custom function for each of these test characteristics.  It would ensure the correct format for your particular problem and is probably faster that all the Googling you're already doing.  Each one should be pretty quick. For example, Sensitivity:

```
sens <- function(ct) { ct[2,2] / sum(ct[,2]) }
```

And Specificity:

```
spec <- function(ct) { ct[1,1] / sum(ct[,1]) }
```

Comment: Thank you for trying to help. I thought about that, but would still need the CIs